# Generating all interaction variables for lm

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, interaction

I have a very basic question:
How do I generate all the interaction effects for linear regression?

I think that with `y~.` I get all main effects and with `y~. + .^2` I get all main effects as well as the 2nd order interactions.

But how do I include the "normal" interaction effects as well? (e.g.`y~x,y,z,x*y,y*z,x*z`)

Or are these already generated by `y~.`? And if so, how do I get only the main effects (e.g. e.g.`y~x,y,z`) for many vairables (n>500).

Thank you in advance and sorry for the basic question.

Comment: I think `y ~ . + .^2` is already correct, or just `y ~ .^2`.

Comment: @Axeman  You are right.  Yours is the same and came first.